# How to get this first order Non-Homogeneous DE?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading a book, and got stuck on this differential equation.

$$
a_1 \frac{dx}{dt} + a_0 x = A\sin(\omega t)
$$

I had tried to solve it by traditional method, but stuck on another problem.

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{a_0}{a_1} x = \frac{A}{a_1} \sin(\omega t)
$$
Let $ \tau = \frac{a_1}{a_0} $, and multiply $e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}$ both sides.

$$
e^{\frac{t}{\tau}} \frac{dx}{dt} + e^{\frac{t}{\tau}} \frac{x}{\tau} = e^{\frac{t}{\tau}} \frac{A}{a_1} \sin(\omega t)
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left( e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}x \right) = e^{\frac{t}{\tau}} \frac{A}{a_1} \sin(\omega t)
$$

$$
\displaystyle \int_{x_0}^{x}d\left( e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}x \right) = \int_{0}^{t} e^{\frac{t}{\tau}} \frac{A}{a_1} \sin(\omega t)dt
$$

$$
\displaystyle e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}(x-x_0) = \frac{A}{a_1} \int_{0}^{t} e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}  \sin(\omega t)dt
$$

But how do I integrate $e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}  \sin(\omega t)$.

Please, help if you know how do I solve this?

Comment: This is just integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ninad said, it is easily solvable using IBP:

$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \dfrac{d}{dx} & \int\\
+\ \ &\ \ \ \ \  \sin(\omega t) & e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\\
-\ \ &\ \ \ \ \ \omega\cos(\omega t) & \tau e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\\
+\ \ &-\omega^2\sin(\omega t) & \tau^2e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}.
\end{aligned}
$$

So

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{I}=\int^t_0 e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\sin{(\omega t)}dt&=\left[\tau e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\sin{(\omega t)}-\omega\tau^2e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\cos{(\omega t)}\right]_0^t-\omega^2\tau^2\underbrace{\int_0^te^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\sin{(\omega t)}dt}_{\mathcal{I}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}\left[\tau e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\sin{(\omega t)}-\omega\tau^2e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\cos{(\omega t)}-(-\omega\tau^2)\right]\\
&=\dfrac{\tau e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\sin{(\omega t)}-\omega\tau^2(e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\cos{(\omega t)}-1)}{1+\omega^2\tau^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. It did solve my problem.